# How to count amount of numbers that occur in set 1 and set 2

Tags: python, set

Hi I tried to find the amount of numbers that occur in both inputs of the user

for example:

```py
s1 = set(input())
s2 = set(input())


setlist = (s1.intersection(s2))
setlist.discard(" ")
print(len(setlist))
```

When the user puts in: 
s1: 1 2 6 8 4 5 7
s2: 10 2 3 4 8

This code will give the answer 3, however, there are 2 numbers that occur in both sets.

The problem is that it treats 10 as a 1 and a 0 independently, instead of just 10.

can someone help me in writing the right code?

thank you!

Comment: This works fine if you fix your syntax error so its a valid set.  Also, you don't need the `setlist.discard`.

Comment: Your code does not compile. s1 = {1 2 6 4 5 7} isn't valid. It sounds like you get a result. I assume this is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line:

```
s1 = set(input())
```

creates a set by iterating on the string returned by `input`, that is, it iterates on its characters:

```
>>> set('1 2 34')
{'3', '2', '1', '4', ' '}
```

You want to build a list of numbers from the input first, by splitting the string and converting the parts to integers:

```
i1 = input('Enter first list of numbers separated by spaces: ')
numbers1 = [int(num) for num in i1.split()]
s1 = set(numbers1)
```

or directly:

```
s1 = set(int(num) for num in i1.split())
```

and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Elements in a set must be divided with commas. So it should be:

```
s1 = {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7}
s2 = {10, 2, 3, 4, 8}
```

Then everything should work

Answer (score 0):

```py
s1 = {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7}
s2 = {10, 2, 3, 4, 8}

setlist = (s1.intersection(s2))
print(len(setlist))
```

Comment: Please, format this as code for readability.

The problem is that he passed a string to a set as iterable. To get the set of integers, he needed `set([int(i) for i in s2.split(" ")])`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25758024)

Answer (score 0):

Because if you get series of characters when you treat a string as an iterable.
If you want structured iteration for string, you should do it manually.
Your input is separated by single space(), so you can split it simply:

```py
input().split()
```

So, answer for your situation:

```py
s1 = set(input().split(' '))
s2 = set(input().split(' '))

setlist = (s1.intersection(s2))
setlist.discard(" ")
print(len(setlist))
```

input and output:

```
1 2 6 8 4 5 7
10 2 3 4 8
3
```

three values(2, 4, 8) are duplicated.